# I want to print a text only if the two buttons are clicked one after the other in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

```
def build(self): 
   layout=FloatLayout()
 
    # use a (r, g, b, a) tuple 

    btn1 = Button(text ="Push Me !",
    background_color =(1, 1, 1,1)
    size =(32, 32), 
    size_hint =(.2, .2), 
    pos =(300, 250)) 

    btn2  = Button(text ="click Me !",
    background_color =(1, 0, 1,1)
    size =(32, 32), 
    size_hint =(.2, .2), 
    pos =(100, 250)) 

    layout.add_widget(btn1)
    layout.add_widget(btn2)

    # I need a function here to print a text only if the two buttons are clicked one after another.

    return  layout
```

Comment: You can for example update a varibale value when the first button is clicked. Then, when the second button is clicked you check the value of this variable if it has the right value you print the text, and of course, you reset the variable.

Comment: Okay sorry about that, but thanks

Comment: @ThunderPheonix could you submit that as an Answer to close this?

Comment: @ti7 It is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example update a varibale value when the first button is clicked. Then, when the second button is clicked you check the value of this variable if it has the right value you print the text, and of course, you reset the variable.

Here is a simple code:

```
var_click = 0
def click1(*events):
     global var_click
     var_click = 1

def click2(*events):
     global var_click
     if var_click == 1:
         var_click = 0
         print("Some text")
```

Then you have just to associate these two functions to `command` parameter of `btn1` and `btn2` respectively.